# Modify cell content when row created in Rad grid

Tags: dynamic, grid, telerik

I have a rad grid dynamically created. I have a status column in database. When binding the value to the grid, I want to show a de-activate button when status is 0 and activate button when status is 1. Upon clicking the button, the status should change from active to inactive and vice versa? What should be the column type and how to write an event for the button click?

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished the same task as shown below :

```
GridButtonColumn btncol = new GridButtonColumn();
btncol.ButtonType = GridButtonColumnType.LinkButton; // setting ButtonType as LinkButton
btncol.DataTextField = "Active"; // setting DataTextField to first column in DataTable
this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(btncol);
```

Better example is given in following link :

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html

Comment: I am creating this grid dyanmically and hence, I can't take any template columns as suggested. If creating template columns is the only solution, how can I do it through code behind?